# VirtualBox Networking Options

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, nat

I'm struggling with understanding the various VB networking options in terms of how they work. I have a Windows 10 Pro laptop with 8GB ram, and my plan is to create/install a few Linux VMs with about 1GB ram each. I'm starting with LMDE 3.

So, if I understand the VB https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#networkingdetails>Manual correctly:

1) NAT means that the VB DHCP server assigns an IP address to each guest, presumably on the same network although from what I understand they won't see each other. Then VB uses NAT to redirect all network traffic from any guest through my laptop's NIC.

2) I'm confused on how NAT Service works and how it's different from NAT.

3) Bridged Networking means that each guest's NIC would really be tunnelled through to my laptop's NIC, so that the VB DHCP server isn't being used and instead the router I have at home (that, for example, assigned an IP to my laptop) would then assign IPs to each guest. This would be similar to if I had 4 physical computers.

4) Internal Networking means that the VB DHCP server assigns an IP address to each guest but also that the guests are set up on a network so that they can see each other. However, my laptop cannot see any of them, and unless I add a second network adapter to any of the guests (using NAT or Bridged, for example), none of the guests will have external Internet access.

5) Host-only Networking means basically the same as Internal Networking, except that my laptop can see the guests (and, so technically, interact with them) but still none of the guests will have external Internet access.

Is any of what I wrote above correct? What about NAT Service? How does that work? I have read through the VirtualBox Manual, but am still confused. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NAT vs NAT Network -

Plain NAT has a predefined subnet, etc and multiple vms wont even see eachother.  It is a simple isolated system with a NAT'd path out.

NAT Network allows you to define the subnet (and have multiple subnets for different groups, etc) and machines on the same NAT Network network can see eachother.

Internal only doesn't have a DHCP service (I use VBox 5.x on Mint 19)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Other than that, everything else I wrote above is correct?